# Is there any option to specify a different dictionary/Custom dictionary for a SpellCheck enabled TextBox?

Tags: wpf

Is there any option to specify the dictionary (if user needs UK standard or German dictionary) in the Spell check enabled Textbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a certain amount of flexibility described [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/text/archive/2009/10/02/custom-dictionaries.aspx).